# PHP CMS not working after change of directory

Tags: php, html

I built(using a tutorial) my CMS in a sub directory on my server and it worked fine. Admin, Archive, full display and synopsis.

I then moved all of this into my main directory, changed the index.php filename to another and used 'include' to display it within a DIV of another page.

It displays the main index.php element of the page but doesn't return articles when they are clicked.

I have searched through the files to change any instances of 'index.php' in the code but there are none. 
All admin functions working perfectly and the output URL onclick of blog entry is the same as the previous files in the previous directory. Of course without formatting but that is no problem.

In what part did I make a mistake? I would like to avoid using an iframe to resolve this issue.

The code that the index.php file is including. (homepage.php)

```
<?php include "templates/include/header.php" ?>

  <ul id="headlines">

<?php foreach ( $results['articles'] as $article ) { ?>

    <li>
      <h2>
        <span class="pubDate"><?php echo date('j F', $article->publicationDate)?></span><a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $article->id?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->title )?></a>
      </h2>
        <p class="summary">
        <?php if ( $imagePath = $article->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ) ) { ?>
          <a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $article->id?>"><img class="articleImageThumb" src="<?php echo $imagePath?>" alt="Article Thumbnail" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->summary )?>
      </p>       
       </li>

<?php } ?>

  </ul>

  <p><a href="./?action=archive">Archivo de Articulos</a></p>

<?php include "templates/include/footer.php" ?>
```

Comment: Some examples of code would be required to help with this, without that we will be guessing at a whole range of things, which wouldn't be useful for you!

Comment: Ok there is quite a lot though. Which page would be having the most effect on this? So I can begin with that

Comment: Download Firebug, and use the "net" tab, to see what's being loaded in the page and what is failing. Doing this will allow you to track down what the pages are really linking to / requesting. Firebug is an extension / add on for the Firefox browser.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo I'm receiving a couple of 404's on some images(not a problem) and then the GET ?action of the file is 200 OK in one log and another is 304 not modified. The response on this is the the index.html, why would it call this? Its completely disconnected.

Comment: Also, using the php file included in the DIV outside as a normal php page is not returning the articles. Despite the fact they are there and the direction is the same. Could this have something to do with the Database?

Comment: @AdamBrown It's a tricky one because I am not familiar with your specific application. Could it be a caching issue? Check both browser and server cache for clearing. Could it be a DNS problem? Have you recently moved a domain etc? Could it be a .htaccess or URL routing issue?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo Haven't changed any of these. And I have chaching disabled, HTML and PHP. Could it have anything to do with the rest of the files in the directory being in HTML?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo would it have anything to do with pulling the content from the database? I thought all tables were global, am I wrong in this and have to respecify a direction

Comment: @AdamBrown If you have BOTH a index.html and an index.php ...I would remove the index.html. It may be the case that index.html has a priority over your PHP page and is therefore getting linked to as the default page. I am not sure what you mean regarding your database, but it would of course be good to check your data if you store links in there.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo nope, just the index.html. I changed the index.php when it arrived in the directory to avoid this. Then referenced the new name in the include.

Comment: It's very like an `.htaccess` rewrite rule that needs to be corrected.